# Type Error: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

I keep getting the 'expected string or bytes-like object ' error and i don't know why. Can anybody help? Thanks!

**VIEW**

```
data = request.POST.get('data')
data_an = time.strptime(request.POST['data'], "%m/%d/%y")
newanal = Analysis(data=data_an)
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<tr>
        <td>Data (DD/MM/YY)</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="data" /></td>
</tr>
```

**MODEL**

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField(null=True)
```

I would insert and save data from template, but when i click Save, i have 'expected string or bytes-like object'

```
data_an 
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=43, tm_isdst=-1)
newanal 
data    
'02/12/15'
request 
('<WSGIRequest\n'
 'path:/addanalysis/,\n'
 'GET:<QueryDict: {}>,\n'
 "POST:{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '5O3kV1Z9iY6SJpIT47Dk1ITcJlWXmOt8',\n"
 " 'data': '02/12/15',\n"

 "COOKIES:{'csrftoken': '5O3kV1Z9iY6SJpIT47Dk1ITcJlWXmOt8',\n"
 " 'sessionid': '296m76ca2ppjkllkmqmeopgjymktl7e1'},\n"
 "META:{'AGSDESKTOPJAVA': 'C:\\\\Program Files "
 "(x86)\\\\ArcGIS\\\\Desktop10.0\\\\',\n"
 " 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\\\ProgramData',\n"
 " 'APPDATA': 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Asus\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming',\n"
 " 'CLASSPATH': "
 "'C:\\\\xpressmp\\\\lib\\\\xprs.jar;C:\\\\xpressmp\\\\lib\\\\xprb.jar;C:\\\\xpressmp\\\\lib\\\\xprm.jar;',\n"
 " 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Common Files',\n"
 " 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Common Files',\n"
 " 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Common Files',\n"
 " 'COMPUTERNAME': 'ASUS-PC',\n"
 " 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\system32\\\\cmd.exe',\n"
 " 'CONFIGSETROOT': 'C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\ConfigSetRoot',\n"
 " 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '199',\n"
 " 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',\n"
 " 'CSRF_COOKIE': '5O3kV1Z9iY6SJpIT47Dk1ITcJlWXmOt8',\n"
 " 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'fileconverter.settings',\n"
 " 'FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING': 'Internet Explorer',\n"
 " 'FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING': 'Default',\n"
 " 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO',\n"
 " 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',\n"
 " 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:',\n"
 " 'HOMEPATH': '\\\\Users\\\\Asus',\n"
 " 'HTTP_ACCEPT': "
 "'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',\n"
 " 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',\n"
 " 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',\n"
 " 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',\n"
 " 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',\n"
 " 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'sessionid=296m76ca2ppjkllkmqmeopgjymktl7e1; '\n"
 "                'csrftoken=5O3kV1Z9iY6SJpIT47Dk1ITcJlWXmOt8',\n"
 " 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',\n"
 " 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',\n"
 " 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addanalisi/',\n"
 " 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',\n"
 " 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
 "'\n"
 "                    '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 "
 "Safari/537.36',\n"
 " 'INCLUDE': 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual '\n"
 "            'Studio\\\\VC98\\\\atl\\\\include;C:\\\\Program Files "
 "(x86)\\\\Microsoft '\n"
 "            'Visual Studio\\\\VC98\\\\mfc\\\\include;C:\\\\Program Files '\n"
 "            '(x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\VC98\\\\include',\n"
 " 'LIB': 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual '\n"
 "        'Studio\\\\VC98\\\\mfc\\\\lib;C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft "
 "Visual '\n"
 "        'Studio\\\\VC98\\\\lib',\n"
 " 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Asus\\\\AppData\\\\Local',\n"
 " 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\\\\\MicrosoftAccount',\n"
 " 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '8',\n"
 " 'OS': 'Windows_NT',\n"
 " 'PATH': 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Cuminas\\\\Document Express DjVu '\n"
 '         '
 "'Plug-in\\\\;C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Oracle\\\\Java\\\\javapath;C:\\\\Program "
 "Files '\n"
 "         '(x86)\\\\NVIDIA '\n"
 "         'Corporation\\\\PhysX\\\\Common;C:\\\\xpressmp\\\\bin;C:\\\\Program "
 "Files '\n"
 "         '(x86)\\\\Intel\\\\iCLS Client\\\\;C:\\\\Program "
 "Files\\\\Intel\\\\iCLS '\n"
 "         'Client\\\\;C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Common Files\\\\Microsoft "
 "Shared\\\\Windows '\n"
 "         'Live;C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Common Files\\\\Microsoft '\n"
 "         'Shared\\\\Windows '\n"
 '         '
 "'Live;C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\system32;C:\\\\WINDOWS;C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\System32\\\\Wbem;C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\System32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\;C:\\\\Program "
 "'\n"
 "         'Files (x86)\\\\Windows Live\\\\Shared;C:\\\\Program Files '\n"
 "         '(x86)\\\\Intel\\\\OpenCL SDK\\\\2.0\\\\bin\\\\x86;C:\\\\Program "
 "Fi... <trimmed 7923 bytes string>
mat 
'1'
data_ca 
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=43, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: If you "keep getting an error", you should post it along with the full traceback.

Comment: Are you working in Python 2.7 oder 3.X? As far as I know they handle strings in different ways.

Comment: i'm working with python 3.5

Comment: The additional information does not show the error. Anyway, have you tried using a `datetime.date` instead of a `time.struct_time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `time.struct_time` object when creating the `Analysis` object which corresponds with a `models.DateField`. The date field doesn't know how to convert the `time.struct_time` to a supported date string, hence the error.

Use a `datetime.date` object instead.

```
from datetime import datetime

data_an = datetime.strptime(request.POST['data'], "%m/%d/%y")
newanal = Analysis(data=data_an)
newanal.save()
```

Alternatively you could construct a valid date string with format `YYYY-MM-DD`, and pass that to the constructor:

```
data_an = time.strptime(request.POST['data'], "%m/%d/%y")
ISO_date = '{}-{:02}-{:02}'.format(data_an.tm_year, data_an.tm_mon, data_an.tm_mday)
newanal = Analysis(data=ISO_date)
```

but I think the former is easier.